# How to merge multiple columns in a file to a single column using bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a text file with three different columns . I want to create another file by merging all these columns into a single column.

my file looks like this

```
mep_kylo_campaigns               mep_primecastaccount        mep_flightstatus
nqs                              tod_do                      gandhi_sub_data 
kylo_register                    policy_record               mep_kylo_jobs   
mep_note                         msg_store                   mep_feature     
nqs_aside                        tbl_employee                mep_profile
```

i want my output like this

```
mep_kylo_campaigns                       
nqs                                                     
kylo_register                                      
mep_note                                                 
nqs_aside                                           
mep_primecastaccount
mep_flightstatus
tod_do
policy_record
msg_store
tbl_employee
gandhi_sub_data
mep_kylo_jobs
mep_feature
mep_profile
```

Comment: Use `ls -1` to get the list in the first place?

Comment: ls -l list all the files , in my case i have a file with 3 columns and i want to merge it  into single column . i tried awk command couldnt figure it out . thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in doing it awk this is the way :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS="" } { for ( i=1; i<= NF ; i++){ print $i"\n"  }  }' input.txt
```

Additionally, if you are seeking to preserve the order of the columns you can use this  :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS="" } { for ( i=1; i<= NF ; i++){ dict[i]=dict[i]$i"\n"  }  } END { for (key in dict) { print dict[key] }  }' input.txt
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you explain your approach, please?

Comment: Sure, its very simple.  Ill simply grab each word, by each line, and print it appending a newline at the end. That way you get a simple column.

Answer (score 9):

This is one way but the order is not the same:

```
$ cat file | tr -s ' ' '\n'
mep_kylo_campaigns
mep_primecastaccount
mep_flightstatus
...
```

**Update**: As useless use of cat was suggested here is another form:

```
$ < file tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

**Update 2**: Above solution only works if columns are separated by space, it won't work for tabs. Following works for both - on GNU `tr` at least:

```
$ < file tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'
```

Comment: Why the useless use of cat? Try `< file tr -s ' ' '\n'`.

Comment: @socowi that works . i tried this for example  < keyspace_exp.txt tr -s ' ' '\n'

Comment: This answer is not correct. The OP asks for columns shown below each other. See the required output in the question.

Comment: @s.ouchene That's how it works, over here at least, if the columns are separated with space as in the sample data, tab separated won't work. I'll edit a tab separated version to the answer as well. Main difference is that it processes rows before columns and the order won't be the same as in the required output.

Comment: @JamesBrown: You need to transpose the file first before using `tr` to replace whitespace with newline characters. Probably you should use `datamash`, or use `cut` with bash process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl Solution that maintains order

```
$ cat globe.txt
mep_kylo_campaigns               mep_primecastaccount        mep_flightstatus
nqs                              tod_do                      gandhi_sub_data
kylo_register                    policy_record               mep_kylo_jobs
mep_note                         msg_store                   mep_feature
nqs_aside                        tbl_employee                mep_profile
$ perl -F"/\s+/"  -lane ' push(@F1,$F[0]);push(@F2,$F[1]);push(@F3,$F[2]); END { print join("\n",@F1,@F2,@F3) } ' globe.txt
mep_kylo_campaigns
nqs
kylo_register
mep_note
nqs_aside
mep_primecastaccount
tod_do
policy_record
msg_store
tbl_employee
mep_flightstatus
gandhi_sub_data
mep_kylo_jobs
mep_feature
mep_profile
$
```